# Draggable & Resizable Container in CodeName One

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to make my custom widget as draggable by setDraggable.

**Part 1:**
My goal is to create a rectangular Container with title (North) having other components in it (Center).
MyWidget should be dragged ONLY if I drag title.

```
public class MyWidget extends Container {

    public MyWidget(String labelText) {

        // Temp size. This will be removed after actual components
        // are put into innerContainer 
        setPreferredH(100);
        setPreferredW(400);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Label title = new Label(labelText);
        addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, title);

        Container innerContainer = new Container();

        addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, innerContainer);
    }

}
```

---

```
Container myWidget = new MyWidget("MyWidget");
myWidget.setDraggable(true);
```

setDraggable() works well when I used it for a Label, but I am not able to drag when I apply same method to MyWidget.

**Part 2:**
Also, Plese suggest how can I make this widget resizable on long press. My goal is to give resizable indicator edges for container on long press & on press, widget enters resize mode. Then I resize component by dragging edges. Resize mode will end if I click outside MyWidget.

**PS**: I noticed dragging is happening 'sometimes' when I click at corner of widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to drag the individual component which is grabbing the drag event. I suggest trying something like:

```
setLeadComponent(title);
```

This will effectively convert the entire hierarchy into a single unified component that changes state together and works as one.

This:

```
setPreferredH(100);
setPreferredW(400);
```

Is a mistake, you shouldn't use setPreferred normally however if you do so you should always use:

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
**Part 1:** Solution makes `title` receive all the events. Any `innerContainer` components (Eg, A `Button`) will not be able to receive event.

Please guide me on **Part 2** also. I am a _new bee_ for CN1.

Comment: Override long press and pointer dragged in the label (you might need to make it focusable). When long press happens activate a mode whereby pointer dragged will resize without invoking super.